# Using R how do I delete duplicates based on multiple columns but select the "most" completed version of the duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a script that would delete based on duplicate values in three columns. There are way more than three columns but i want to delete based on those specific ones

```
DF2021 <-DF2021 [!duplicated (DF2021[,c("column1","column2","column3")]),]
```

The script above works and it leaves me with one row for each time there is a duplicate based on those three columns.

The next step is where I wonder how to make sure I'am left with the row based on criteria. For example I want the row with the least NA's.

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column 7
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm  Hospital    NA
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm     NA       NA
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    NA       NA       NA
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     NA       NA       NA
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm     NA       NA
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm   Garden    Run
  Mar     Thu    2020   Red     Cold   Desk      Bus
```

In the end I would expect the duplicate value to leave me with three rows.

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column 7
Jan      Tue   2020    Blue    Warm   Hospital   NA
Feb      Thu   2020     Red    Warm   Garden    Run
Mar      Thu   2020     Red    Cold   Desk      Bus
```

Note that if i were to do

```
DF2021 <- DF2021[complete.cases(DF2021),]
```

It would only give me the Feb and Mar row but not the Jan. I want the script to remove duplicates and take the "most" but doesn't have to "full" rows out of the duplicates based on those three rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can create a function to detect the complete rows and those with only one `NA`. With that you can use indexing and select that rows. Here the code:

```
#Index for selection
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- length(which(is.na(x)))
  y <- ifelse(y<=1,1,0)
  return(y)
}
#Apply
index <- which(apply(df,1,myfun)==1)
#Output
out <- df[index,]
```

Output:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5  column6 column7
1     Jan     Tue    2020    Blue    Warm Hospital    <NA>
6     Feb     Thu    2020     Red    Warm   Garden     Run
7     Mar     Thu    2020     Red    Cold     Desk     Bus
```